# Laravel locale not taking other date formating

Tags: php, laravel, locale

In Laravel, I'm running into a problem of formating, whenether I'm formating a date :

```php
utf8_encode(strftime("%d %B %Y", $c_d->getTimestamp()))
```

or

```php
$c_d->format("d/B/Y")
```

it is being English formatted. In `config/app.php` I have set `'locale' => 'fr'`. The only way I can have french date formatting on date is to put `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');` in front of each formatting call which is a pain.

Is there a way to tackle that ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the great [Carbon library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) which already is shipped with Laravel. Carbon detects the language set inside the `config/app.php` file and formats the date accordingly.

You can try this with using the [`now()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now) or by utilizing the Carbon instance like this:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

// Output example: Dec 25, 1975
$myDate = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($ts)-> toFormattedDateString();
```